# scala: complicated flatMap on a tuple of Options

Tags: scala, flatmap, scala-option

My data type is: `List[(Option[Set[Long]], Option[Set[(Long, Long)]])]` (i.e. a List of a 2-tuple of Options, one is for a Set of Long, one is for a Set of a 2-tuple of Longs). E.g.:

```
val l = List((Option(Set(1L, 2L, 3L)), Option(Set((4L, 5L), (6L, 7L)))))
```

I wish to flatMap this List into a `List[Set[Long]]` type, in a way that each of the first elements of the second Option, would be concatenated to a new Set with the first Option. So the desired result here is:

```
List(Set(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Set(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L))
```

This works fine with the following code:

```
l.flatMap {
 case(setOpt1, setOpt2) =>
 val set1 = setOpt1.getOrElse(Set[Long]());
 val set2 = setOpt2.getOrElse(Set[(Long, Long)]());
 set2.map(k => set1 ++ Set(k._1))
 }
```

The plot thickens when the second Option is `None`, and the first Option "exists", e.g.:

```
val l = List((Option(Set(1L, 2L, 3L)), None))
```

And assume I have no way of avoiding this. In this case I would like to get the first Set as is:

```
List(Set(1L, 2L, 3L))
```

However, using the same code as above the `set2` value becomes an empty Set, and the `map` means nothing in this case, and I would get an empty List:

```
res60: List[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Long]] = List()
```

So, how do I do this? Preferably elegantly :)

Comment: You stated what should happen for `(Some,Some)` and for `(Some,None)`. What about `(None,Some)` and `(None,None)`?

Comment: `(None, None)` and `(None,Some)` both work as expected: first case returns an empty List, second case returns `List(Set(4L), Set(6L))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add case statements to handle each combination of `Option`

```
def g(l:List[(Option[Set[Long]], Option[Set[(Long, Long)]])]) = l.flatMap{
  case (Some(single), None) =>
    List(single)
  case (Some(single), Some(tuple)) =>
    tuple.map(k => single ++ Set(k._1))
  case (None, Some(tuple)) =>
    tuple.map(k => Set(k._1))
  case (None, None) =>
    List()
```

}

This produces the result that you are expecting. Here are all the tests I ran:

```
val l1 = List((Option(Set(1L, 2L, 3L)), Option(Set((4L, 5L), (6L, 7L)))))
g(l1)
res0: List[Set[Long]] = List(Set(1, 2, 3, 4), Set(1, 2, 3, 6))

val l2 = List((Option(Set(1L, 2L, 3L)), None))
g(l2)
res1: List[Set[Long]] = List(Set(1, 2, 3))

val l3 = List((None, Option(Set((4L, 5L), (6L, 7L)))))
g(l3)
res2: List[Set[Long]] = List(Set(4), Set(6))

val l4 = List((None, None))
g(l4)
res3: List[Set[Long]] = List()
```

Comment: But it doesn't produce the desired result for the first example: `g(List((Option(Set(1L, 2L, 3L)), Option(Set((4L, 5L), (6L, 7L)))))) ~>
res8: List[Iterable[Any]] = List(List(Set(1, 2, 3), 4), List(Set(1, 2, 3), 6))`

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke correct, I did not see that before accepting. narryddubbs can you fix this to keep the accept?

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke Nice catch. I updated the answer to correct that.

Comment: I think `flatMap` is not needed here, one could just use `map`.

Comment: No you need `flatmap` in the implementation

Comment: Oh I see, you'll get nested lists with `map`.